# How would I get the height of my header?

Tags: html, css

So I have a fixed header that DOESN'T have a height specified. It just resizes however it wants according to screen size. But, its fixed so the form below it needs a margin-top so it doesn't sit in front behind it and over it. Would I need to specify a size for the header?

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  /*background-color: white;*/
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
}

form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*margin-top: 10%;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

form input {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="includes/php/done.php">done</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<form class="login">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input id="loginbtn" type="button" name="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

You can see the commented code(2 lines) and you'll kinda see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) specifically says:

> **fixed**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space
>   is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is
>   positioned relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when
>   scrolled.

So that means you can't use the position to position elements behind it with CSS.

You have two options:

1. Use `position:sticky`. This will place the form directly below the `offsetHeight` of the header. It will not take into account your box-shadow, so you will still need to add a `margin-top:4px` in the form to take that into account.
2. Use Javascript to both calculate automatically the header height and the boxShadow height:

```js
// get total height for <header>, including padding
var headerEl = document.getElementById("header");
var headerHeight = +headerEl.offsetHeight;
var headerBoxShadow = window.getComputedStyle(headerEl).boxShadow;
var headerBoxShadowY = +headerBoxShadow.split("px")[2].trim();

// set margin-top to <form> depending on <header> height
var formEl = document.getElementById("form");
formEl.style.marginTop = headerHeight + headerBoxShadowY + 'px';
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
}

form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

form input {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="includes/php/done.php">done</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<form class="login" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input id="loginbtn" type="button" name="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with different approaches. One easy way I'd suggest (might be not best approach, but easy one) is duplicate the header and make it hidden with position "static". Like so:

```
<!-- original header -->
<header>
    ...
</header>

<!-- duplicated header -->
<header style="position: static; visibility: hidden;">
    ...
</header>

<form>
    ...
</form>
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1shwgqcs/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple approach. You won't need to know the height of the header in this case.

```
<div id=1>          // flex, verticle, vh=100
  <div id=2></div>  // your header, position sticky top
  <div id=3></div>  // flex-fill
</div>
```